# How to zero out the time for UTC format date in momentjs

Tags: javascript, date, momentjs

I have this

```
    const appointmentTime = '2019-10-24T08:50:00+10:00'; 
    const x = appointmentTime
        ? serverDateStringToDate(appointmentTime).set({
                hour: 0,
                minute: 0,
                second: 0,
                millisecond: 0
          })
        : null;
```

Also

```
export const serverDateTimeFormat = 'YYYY-MM-DDTHH:mm:ssZ';
export const serverDateStringToDate = dateString => moment(dateString, serverDateTimeFormat).startOf('day');
```

I set the hour, minute, second and millisecodn to zero however still it shows

```
"2019-10-24T08:50:00+10:00"
```

Any idea why?

Comment: Nothing in the code in your question _"shows"_ anything. Where are you seeing that date/time string? Also, what is the point of your ternary expression? `appointmentTime` is never _falsy_?

Comment: I am debugging thats why I hardcoded appointment Time :-|

Comment: I can't reproduce this in my browser, so I believe that there's something else in your code that you aren't covering

Comment: Any chance you could address the first part of my comment?

Comment: I see that tie string when console log the x variable

Comment: You're looking at the internals of a moment.js object. Try actually displaying the value as a string, eg `x.toISOString()`

Comment: Cannot reproduce this ~ https://jsfiddle.net/n4e8xzvf/

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/UTC - then try `yourUTCDate.toJSON()`.

Comment: when I use x.toISOString() it prints out 2019-10-23T13:00:00.000Z

Comment: Which is correct (`toISOString()` prints in UTC, hence the hour). Here's a version using `format()` ~ https://jsfiddle.net/415hpzrb/

Comment: Thanks you resolved my problem I were looking at the internal moment object